# How can i get the startAngle and endAngle of each arc in the sunburst example using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy, sunburst-diagram

I want to get the start and end angles for each arc in the sunburst example as in http://bl.ocks.org/4063423:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can see them in the code:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });
```

So your start angle is in the x attribute and x + dx give your end angle.

The trick is that the x, dx, y and dy are all set by the layout function:

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });
```

sort(null) tells it not to reorder your data
size(...) tells it the output range for x and y coordinate (radius is squared because we are mapping to an area).
value(...) is the value accessor for how to weight each item.

Comment: I tried to use the Cofee flavour wheel [link](http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/) and incorporate labels and zoom into Sun-burst. However, i want to show the weight of each item in the value and also hide labels when the arc is less than .01(d.dx < .01). This works initially, but not on click.The labels appear even when the arc size is less than .01. How can i get the corresponding path size for the labels on click? Js Fiddle with code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sreedivyapunukollu/QCqhj/3/)JS Fiddle for full Result: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sreedivyapunukollu/QCqhj/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: In your text transition end function I am not sure why you ever set st=d, it seems to work if you always use e. But you might need to compute a better dx after click since otherwise you might have large wedges that are still < 0.01. You want the proportion of the new wedge size so try e.dx / d.dx (d is the parent). See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/QCqhj/4/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this simple code:

```
...
.data(partition.nodes)
.filter(function(d) { // You're not restricted to use the "filter" function
   var startAngle = arc.startAngle()(d);
   var endAngle = arc.endAngle()(d);
});
...
```

Comment: Interesting alternative – returns the angle in radians as opposed to degrees/360.